# problem with permutation

Tags: probability

In how many ways can the letters of the word "ALPHABET" be arranged , if vowels are retain to their places , if consonants are retain to their places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In how many ways can the letters of the word "ALPHABET" be arranged , if vowels are retain to their places , if consonants are retain to their places?

How many ways are there to arrange the vowels, $\rm AAE$ among their places?

How many ways are there to arrange the consonants, $\rm LPHBT$ among their places?

How many ways are there to do both these tasks in series?